# Linux dd is stuck writing to md0, does anyone see problem?

Tags: linux, dd

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and have an md0 raid array of 4x500GB drives, ie. 2TB

I ran this command `dd if=/dev/zero of=./swapfile bs=1MiB count=350KiB`

Which I expected to create a 350GB file,

However the command is stuck, it has not returned and the file size is not longer growing, has been same for 20 minutes now.

```
$ ls -lrt
total 311956800
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 319443763200 Apr  7 17:59 swapfile
$ 
$ df -k .
Filesystem      1K-blocks      Used  Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/md0       1953017856 262744128 1689747456  14% /mnt/nvme1
```

What is issue?

ps: I did this

```
$ strace -p 2318
strace: Process 2318 attached
^C^C^C^C

^C^C^C^C^C
^C^C^C
```

There was no output, and I could not unattach... CTRL-C does not work.

Comment: do you have `strace` installed? see what it says. `strace -p $(pidof dd)`  (or check the PID manually)

Comment: ```# strace -p 2318
strace: Process 2318 attached``` (there is not other output)

Comment: that's _all_? Usually it at least shows e.g. `read(0, ` if the process is blocking on a system call. Anyway, if there is more, you might want to [edit] it to the question, the formatting in comments isn't very good for printouts like that

Comment: Which state is the `dd` process in (see `ps -f 2318`)?

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps someone else.... The filesystem was BTRFS (I probably should have mentioned that but it did not occur to me) -- I just formatted /dev/md0 as EXT4 -- and as if by magic everything started working. :-)